# ReQL equivalent of Select * from table where id in ()

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

I am new to RethinkDB, I have an array of object ids, I want to fetch object from a table whose id belong to this array.

SQL query would be -

```
SELECT * FROM orgs WHERE id IN ('ID1','ID2');
```

I tried following in myREQL console-

```
r.table("orgs").filter(function(org) {
  r.expr(["ID1" ,"ID2"]).contains(org['id'])
})
```

It gave me error -

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I referred this https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/contains/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return value of expr and org['id'] is needed to be changed to org('id'). I think the code below works:

```
  r.table("orgs").filter(function(org) {
  return r.expr(["ID1" ,"ID2"]).contains(org('id'))
  })
```